# In Xcode, how to not run certain Run Script Build Phases when running Tests?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, aggregate, target

My project is currently setup so that the MyApp target includes a few Run Script Build Phases. These scripts depend on the sequence of Build Phases. For example, there's a script that runs before Copy Bundle Resources and another one that runs afterwards.

My test target depends on MyApp, so when I run the tests (Product Menu, Test), I'd like to not include some of these scripts because it slows the testing down.

I thought to create an Aggregate Target which includes MyApp target. Then move the scripts I don't want to run when testing out of MyApp and into the Aggregate. However, I don't see how I can configure the same sequence of when these scripts will run by doing this.

Is there a way to do this? Or perhaps a better solution all together?

Comment: I believe run scripts have a **Run script only when installing** option.  Will that help you?

Comment: @PetahChristian That won't completely help as at least one script needs to run each build, not just when installing.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what your scripts doing:

- You can create a Pre-Action (go to "edit-scheme") - there you can add a run script and it will be only executed when your running selected scheme.
  What you have to know is: Pre-Actions are on another thread, so if you want to stop the building process it won't work
- If its possible: You can check your script if "debuging" or "releasing"
  you can use this if its enough to check just this two options like:

  ```
  wantedConfig="Debug"; currentConfig="$CONFIGURATION"    
  if [ $currentConfig=$wantedConfig ]; then
    echo "Now Im on a debug mode and will do all you want here";
  fi
  ```
- You also can create your own environments variables like:

**TEST_MODE=YES**

..and use it like example above:

**currentConfig="$TEST_MODE"**

Comment: I tried adding env vars to both the host and the test schemes, for both "run" and "test" configurations, but in all 4 cases I got the empty echo output, like: `echo "HOST_TEST_VAR = $HOST_TEST_VAR"` outputs `HOST_TEST_VAR =`.

Answer (score 0):

> It depends on what your scripts doing:
>
> You can create a Pre-Action (go to "edit-scheme") - there you can add
> a run script and it will be only executed when your running selected
> scheme. What you have to know is: Pre-Actions are on another thread,
> so if you want to stop the building process it won't work
>
> If its possible: You can check your script if "debuging" or
> "releasing" you can use this if its enough to check just this two
> options like:
>
> wantedConfig="Debug"; currentConfig="$CONFIGURATION"     if [
> $currentConfig=$wantedConfig ]; then   echo "Now Im on a debug mode
> and will do all you want here"; fi You also can create your own
> environments variables like:
>
> TEST_MODE=YES
>
> ..and use it like example above:
>
> currentConfig="$TEST_MODE"

The logic is there, but it keeps coming inside the if even thoug the configuration is different. After some debugging and searching this is the working snippet :

```
wantedConfig="PROD"
currentConfig="${CONFIGURATION}"  
echo "currentConfig = $CONFIGURATION"
if [ "$currentConfig" = "$wantedConfig" ]; then
    echo "begin action"
fi
```

Comment: What's the point of quoting the other answer in its entirely? You can just link to it if this answer is meant to correct it.

Comment: As i said, when i tried to just copy and paste the snippet given, it keeps coming inside the if even though the actual value is different. I don't know why it doesn't work , i am not that familiar with scripting syntax and stuff. But after some debugging (i added space between the = inside the if), now it works. I attach the snippet to help people that have no extra time wondering what's wrong with it.